# Is there a better pattern for 'nested' UI select controls [Users can use THEESE or THIS]

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, design-patterns, design, component

Is there a good UI pattern for this sort of specific select case?

There is a search field for labels/tags. The user has 3 options they can select from to refine their search. These options are grouped into two sets.

**Set 1:** 2 options ['Case sensitivity' & 'Starts with'], the user can select one or both of these options.

**Set 2:** 1 option [Switch to 'Regex' syntax].

The user can use either or both options from Set 1 but not Set 2 or they can use Set 2 but not any of the options from set 1.

Essentialy it boils down to you can use THESE [Set 1] OR you can use THIS [Set 2]. Set 1 acts like a set of checkboxes whereas Set 2 is more like a radio button.

Without using checkboxes and a radio button how else could i best provide this functionality in a UI that still looks and feels intuitive.

**Here is the current design:** The icons don't really feel standard aside from the case senstivity so i'm not sure how much value they add:

[image: Current design in product]

**Here is my proposed solution:** Using switches and lables to make things clearer but would still require a level of experiential learning and interacting with the components to figure out how it works.

[image: Proposed solution]

FYI: Ideally I would usability test this new design but I haven't been afford the time to do this which is less than ideal!

Comment: Personally, I dislike the icons in the second example. Why have them at all? To me they just add more clutter and no additional benefit to the also present text. [Without the icons, it looks much cleaner to me](https://i.imgur.com/YzGKEqi.png).

Comment: Very late to get back to this but what you suggested is actually what I ended up doing. The icons served no purpose so we simply left them out!

Comment: Thanks a lot, @DannyW86, I feel honored 

Comment: Do you have some user or usage data on this now to help inform the better pattern to use?